# Django make a double foreign key lookup involving one to many to one relations

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset, one-to-many

I have the following models:

```
def Order(models.Model):
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Receiver)
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse)

def Receiver(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) #this is not made one to one because user can have more than one receiver
    name = ...
    zipcode = ...

def Warehouse(models.Model):
    city = ...
    street = ...
```

I want to select all `Warehouse` entries related to request.User object. The only way i can do this now is:

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(receiver__user=request.User)
# here i set orders warehouse ids to list called ids
user_warehouses = Warehouse.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)
```

But i have a strong feeling that i am inventing the wheel. Is there a more simple Django-way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Warehouse.objects.filter(order__receiver__user=request.user)
```

you can traverse relations backwards ("reverse lookup") and traverse multiple levels with the double-underscore syntax

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: But a `Warehouse` model dose not have `order` field, it can only give us `order_set`

Comment: with objects you have to do `a_warehouse.order_set.filter(whatever)` but with lookups, as described in the docs, you just use the lowercase name of the related model